# Ant compiles but no class files

Tags: java, ant

I've pulled an old java application project out of the svn and am having a a royal pain to get it to compile properly with ANT.  ANT claims "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" however  no class files.

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="all" name="myproj">
   <property environment="env" />
   <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src" />
   <property name="bin.dir" value="${basedir}/bin" />   
   <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
   <property name="cache.dir" value="${bin.dir}/.cache" />
   <property name="config.dir" value="${basedir}/config" />
   <property name="data.dir" value="${basedir}/data" />
   <property name="images.dir" value="${data.dir}/images" />
   <property name="doc.dir" value="${basedir}/docs" />
   <property name="install.dir" value="${env.JAVA_APPS}/myproj" />
   <property name="debug.flag" value="on" />

   <echo> ${ant.project.name}</echo>
   <echo> Ant version: ${ant.version}</echo>
   <echo> Ant Java version: ${ant.java.version}</echo>
   <echo> Java version: ${java.version}</echo>

    <!-- **********************************************************************
    compile, compile the source
    *********************************************************************** --> 
   <target name="compile" depends="prepare">
         <depend srcdir="${src.dir}"
                destdir="${bin.dir}" 
                cache="${cache.dir}"
                closure="yes"/>
        <javac destdir="${bin.dir}"
               debug="${debug.flag}"
               deprecation="on"
               fork="false"
               includeantruntime="false">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </javac>      
   </target>

</project>
```

Compile:

> t1@hostname1(/export/t1/JAVA)$ ant -verbose compile

```
ant -verbose compile                             
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010     
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /export/t1/JAVA/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_11/jre                                                                                             
Detected OS: Linux                                                                                                                                   
parsing buildfile /export/t1/JAVA/build.xml with URI = file:/export/t1/JAVA/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /export/t1/JAVA  
parsing buildfile jar:file:/export/t1/FOSS/apache-ant-1.8.2/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/export/t1/FOSS/apache-ant-1.8.2/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file                                          
 [property] Loading Environment env.
     [echo]  myproj         
     [echo]  Ant version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
     [echo]  Ant Java version: 1.7                                   
     [echo]  Java version: 1.7.0_11                     
Build sequence for target(s) `compile' is [init, prepare, compile]
Complete build sequence is [init, prepare, compile, mklib, all, install, clean]

...

compile:
    [javac] com/gis/GISUtils.java added as com/gis/GISUtils.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com/gis/advisory/Advisory.java added as com/gis/advisory/Advisory.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] com/gis/application/TabbedApplication.java added as com/gis/application/TabbedApplication.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] ... 874 files remaining removed for brevity


 [javac] Compiling 877 source files to /export/t1/JAVA/bin       
    [javac] Using modern compiler                                 
    [javac] Compilation arguments:                                             
    [javac] '-deprecation'                                              
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] '/export/t1/JAVA/bin'                                 
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] '< list of all my jars ...>' 


 [javac] '-sourcepath'                                                                              
    [javac] '/export/t1/JAVA/src'                              
    [javac] '-g'    
    [javac]                                                      
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are 
    [javac] not part of the command.                                                    
    [javac] Files to be compiled:                                  
    [javac]    /export/t1/JAVA/src/com/gis/GISUtils.java
    [javac]     /export/t1/JAVA/src/com/gis/advisory/Advisory.java
    [javac]     /export/t1/JAVA/src/com/gis/application/TabbedApplication.java 
    [javac]     ... 874 files remaining removed for brevity


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

Build successful but no class files in the bin dir.

```
t1@hostname1(/export/t1/JAVA)$ ll bin/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x. 3 t1 t1 4.0K Sep 11 22:32 .
drwxrwxr-x. 9 t1 t1 4.0K Sep 11 22:30 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 2 t1 t1 4.0K Sep 11 22:32 .cache
```

the java files are found, hmmm..., I've tried several differnt configurations and still nothing.  Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is `ll` an alias for `ls -l`?  I'm wondering what's causing `total 12K` to appear in its output.

Comment: @VGR yes, ll is an alias for 'ls -l' or 'ls -alF'

Comment: That `total 12K` line seems to imply that the files are present, though I don't know why they aren't showing up in a listing.  Does `find bin/ -name .cache -prune -o -print` display any files?  On what type of filesystem does the project reside?  (I don't know offhand of a filesystem that allows files to be hidden from `ls -a`, but I wouldn't be surprised if such a thing exists.)

Comment: have you tried with the `verbose="true"` attribute in your javac task? Does that show any clue as to what's done to the class files?

Comment: @VGR A linux directory listings is 4096B/4k no matter the contents.  the 'll bin' is listing 3 directories. The .cache dir is empty.

Comment: @Lolo I set "verbose = true" as suggested and it appears that everything is in order.

Comment: @brad12s It seems to be a bit more complicated than that, as `..` varies in size depending on the contents of the parent directory (at least on my system), but your point is correct.  The `total 12K` is not indicative of any issues.

Comment: @brad12s Did you find a solution to that problem? I got the exact same issue and would like to fix it ASAP. Thank you.